# Postman Tests - Conditioning with http status

Tags: javascript, http, testing, http-status-code-404, postman

I want to check if an answer is ok. It is either correct when the response code is 200 or 500. Latter needs to differentiate between a String in the response body to be correct or incorrect. It should be in a single test.

I already tried simple if-clauses, but they do not work.

```
pm.test("response is ok", function(){
    if(pm.response.to.have.status(200)){
        //do things
    }     
});
```

### Edit:

The Solution i used is

```
pm.test("response is valid", function(){
if(pm.response.code === 200){
    //is ok
} else if (pm.response.code === 500){
    if(pm.expect(pm.response.json().message).to.include("xyz")){
        //is ok
    } else {
       pm.expect.fail("Error 500"); 
    }
} else {
    pm.expect.fail("statuscode not 200 or 500");
}
```

});

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be something basic that would log that message to the console if the status code was `200`:

```
pm.test('Check Status', () => {
    if(pm.response.code === 200) {
        console.log("It's 200")
    }
})
```

If you then needed to check something in the `response body` after, you could do something like the example below.

This is just sending a simple `GET` request to `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`

The response body of this would be:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

We can add a check in the `Tests` tab, to confirm that the `id` property has a value of `1`, it would only run this check if the `response code` was `200`:

```
if(pm.response.code === 200) {
    pm.test('Check a value in the response', () => {
        pm.expect(pm.response.json().id).to.eql(1)
    })
}
```

This is a very basic and a very simple example of what you could do. It would be more complex depending on your own context but hopefully it explains how you could do it.

Comment: Thanks. The "pm.respone.code ===200" and pm.expect.*  was what i needed. I added my solution in the Question.

Comment: I came here to look for the answer and then I found the official way of doing it. It's described in Postman documentation:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#making-assertions-on-the-http-response

The key part is  "pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201,202]);"

Answer (score 0):

Is the request asynchronous or syncronous?
Maybe you are trying to check a response that has not arrived yet.

Try this to send the request asynchronously:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "https://my-end-point-url", true);
xhr.send();
```

Then use this to process the request and display the response as a pop-up:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(response)
  }
}
```